# Running advertisement through the foursquare API

Tags: ios, foursquare

I was wondering if anyone knew if you could run foursquare's advertising (location based promotions, priority recommendations etc) through a third party app to generate revenue for that app. 
And if this is not an option, any viable alternatives?